# Router Areas in .NET Core 3.1 Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-core-3.1, area

### This is my root folder .NET Core Web Application

[image]

I had try  **[Route("mynewarea/[controller]/[action]")]** in Areas but it not working

### My code in the Startup.cs file

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
//Routing App
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
   // Routing Area
   endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
      name: "Areas",
      areaName: "Areas",
      pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
   //Routing Controller
   endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
       name: "default",
       pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
      //Handle to Error Page
});
```

And i had references in this link [Area endpoint routing in asp.net core 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59781531/area-endpoint-routing-in-asp-net-core-3-1) but int [doc](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1) of Microsoft said **Security patch**

### Problem

---

> http://localhost:xxxx/TIMS //It is not working

---

> http://localhost:xxxx/TIMS/Home/Index // work

### Expect

http://localhost:xxxx/TIMS //Work

Comment: Did you check the Pages Folder?

Comment: I don't use Pages Folder

Comment: Aren't your two URL actaully webpages in the Page Folder?